# add 8 to my randomly generated array

Tags: javascript, arrays

As the title suggests, I want to add 8 to my randomly generated array. For example if the array produces the following: [8,64,92,3,65,23,76,92]. Underneath this array I want the following to appear [16,72,100,11..etc].

How would I go about doing this. I tried `var newarray = arr +8`  but this just added 8 to the last value in the array.

```
var arr = []
    function array() {

while(arr.length < 8){
    var randomnumber = Math.ceil(Math.random()*100)
    if(arr.indexOf(randomnumber) > -1) continue;
    arr[arr.length] = randomnumber;
}
document.getElementById('Output').innerHTML = "Array values before the update:" + "<br>" + arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use like this [`Array#map`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjR2JPtjr_TAhUIR48KHfItA5MQFggiMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fmap&usg=AFQjCNG-88X_4BP621jc1yLUJwBxSXgcxg&sig2=z5fgRDmpwqBnxLBnjndOuQ)

```js
var a = [8,64,92,3,65,23,76,92];

console.log(a.map(a => a+8))
```

Comment: Happy to help...:-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest make use of Array.prototype.map

You can use arrow function:

```
function add(arr){
    return arr.map(a => a+8));
}
```

or do this without es6:

```
function add(arr){
    return arr.map(function(a){
        return a+8;
    });
};
```